# How to fit big table in a single page without changes in margins?

Tags: tables, formatting, margins, page-breaking, longtable

I've shown two tables in the below code, one with changes in page margin and other is without change in margin. As per rule I can't change page margin even slightly and I've only one page for this table, and this table is not fitting properly in one page. Please suggest me a way(anyway) to fit this table properly in one page.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\newenvironment{changemargin}[1]{
  \begin{list}{}{
    \setlength{\voffset}{#1}
  }
  \item[]}{\end{list}}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\title{topic}

\titlerunning{Hamiltonian Mechanics}
\author{Author}
\authorrunning{at}
\institute{Insti\\
\email{email} \hspace{3mm} \email{email2}}
\maketitle        

\begin{abstract}
abc 
\keywords{xyz}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{changemargin}{-1.5cm}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.6mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{table}
{\rowcolors{2}{gray!0!black!0}{gray!0!white!0}

\begin{adjustwidth}{-3.25cm}{} 
\begin{tabular}{ |p{8.5cm}|p{8.5cm}|  }
\hline
\hspace{2.5cm} \textbf{\uline{Fffffff Fffff Fffff}} \vspace{2mm}& \hspace{2.5cm}\textbf{\uline{Nnnnnn Nnnnn Nnnnn}} \\
\hline \hline

\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss} } \\
 \hline

\begin{itemize}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 

\item[] asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj 

\end{itemize}

& 

\begin{itemize}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 

\item[] asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj 

\end{itemize}

\\

\hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss} } \\
 \hline




\begin{itemize}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
\item[] asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj 


\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 

\item[] asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj 
\end{itemize}


& 

\begin{itemize}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
\item[] asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj 


\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 

\item[] asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj 
\end{itemize}


\\

\hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss} } \\
 \hline


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{flushleft}

\begin{displaymath}
\hspace{-0.70cm}\xymatrixcolsep{1pc}
\xymatrix{
  & &  \mathbf{m[x][x]} \ar[dl] \ar[dr] & \\ 
   &  \mathbf{m[x][x]/\textit{m(x,x)}}  \ar[dr] & & \mathbf{m[x][x]/\textit{m(m,x)}} \ar[dl]  \\
  & & \mathbf{m[x]/\varphi(x)\cong x(x\textsuperscript{x})}   & &
}
\end{displaymath}
\end{flushleft}

 &

\begin{center}
\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrixcolsep{4.5pc}
\hspace{-2.25cm} \xymatrix{
  & &  \mathbf{\mathbb{K}[x]} \ar[dl] \ar[dr] & \\ 
   &  \mathbf{\mathbb{K}[x]/\textit{m(x)} =  \mathbb{K}[a]}  \ar[dr] & & \mathbf{\mathbb{K}[x]} \ar[dl]  \\
  & & \mathbf{\mathbb{K}/k\mathbb{K}}  & &
}
%\end{adjustwidth}
\end{displaymath}

 % \end{flushright} 

 \end{center} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

  \\


\hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss} } \\
 \hline

\begin{itemize}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 

\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 

\end{itemize}

&

\begin{itemize}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 

\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 

\end{itemize}

\\  

\hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss}} \\
 \hline

\begin{itemize}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 
\end{itemize}

&

\begin{itemize}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 
\end{itemize}

\\

\hline  
\end{tabular}
\caption{ FFF and NNN }
 \end{adjustwidth}
}
\end{table}
\end{changemargin}



%\begin{changemargin}{-1.5cm}


\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.6mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{table}



{\rowcolors{2}{gray!0!black!0}{gray!0!white!0}
%\begin{adjustheight}{2}{}
%\begin{adjustwidth}{-3.25cm}{} 
\begin{tabular}{ |p{8.5cm}|p{8.5cm}|  }
\hline

\hspace{2.5cm} \textbf{\uline{Functon Fffff Fffff}} \vspace{2mm}& \hspace{2.5cm}\textbf{\uline{Nnnnnn Nnnnn Nnnnn}} \\
\hline \hline

\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss} } \\
 \hline

\begin{itemize}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 

\item[] asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj 

\end{itemize}

& 

\begin{itemize}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 

\item[] asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj 

\end{itemize}

\\

\hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss} } \\
 \hline




\begin{itemize}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
\item[] asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj 


\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 

\item[] asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj 
\end{itemize}


& 

\begin{itemize}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
\item[] asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj 


\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 

\item[] asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj 
asmlj asmlj 
\end{itemize}


\\

\hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss} } \\
 \hline


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{flushleft}

\begin{displaymath}
\hspace{-0.70cm}\xymatrixcolsep{1pc}
\xymatrix{
  & &  \mathbf{m[x][x]} \ar[dl] \ar[dr] & \\ 
   &  \mathbf{m[x][x]/\textit{m(x,x)}}  \ar[dr] & & \mathbf{m[x][x]/\textit{m(m,x)}} \ar[dl]  \\
  & & \mathbf{m[x]/\varphi(x)\cong x(x\textsuperscript{x})}   & &
}
\end{displaymath}
\end{flushleft}

 &

\begin{center}
\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrixcolsep{4.5pc}
\hspace{-2.25cm} \xymatrix{
  & &  \mathbf{\mathbb{K}[x]} \ar[dl] \ar[dr] & \\ 
   &  \mathbf{\mathbb{K}[x]/\textit{m(x)} =  \mathbb{K}[a]}  \ar[dr] & & \mathbf{\mathbb{K}[x]} \ar[dl]  \\
  & & \mathbf{\mathbb{K}/k\mathbb{K}}  & &
}
%\end{adjustwidth}
\end{displaymath}

 % \end{flushright} 

 \end{center} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

  \\


\hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss} } \\
 \hline

\begin{itemize}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 

\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 

\end{itemize}

&

\begin{itemize}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 

\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 

\end{itemize}

\\  

\hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss}} \\
 \hline

\begin{itemize}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 
\end{itemize}

&

\begin{itemize}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
\item[] aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas 
asas asas asas asas asas 
\end{itemize}

\\

\hline  
\end{tabular}
\caption{ FFF and NNN }
% \end{adjustwidth}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, using `enumitem` and `nccmath` for its `\medmath` command to have mediums-sized formulae: it allows to reduce the size of the commutative diagrams:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newenvironment{changemargin}[1]{
  \begin{list}{}{
    \setlength{\voffset}{#1}
  }
  \item[]}{\end{list}}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{mathtools}
 \numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{array, tabularx, nccmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\title{topic}
\titlerunning{Hamiltonian Mechanics}
\author{Author}
\authorrunning{at}
\institute{Insti\\
\email{email} \hspace{3mm} \email{email2}}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
abc
\keywords{xyz}
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.6mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.333}
\setlist[itemize, 1]{label=$ \bullet $, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, topsep=0pt, before=\vspace*{-1.8ex}, after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table}
{\rowcolors{2}{gray!0!black!0}{gray!0!white!0}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\centering \textbf{\uline{Fffffff Fffff Fffff}} \vspace{2mm}& {\centering\textbf{\uline{Nnnnnn Nnnnn Nnnnn}}} \\
\hline \hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss} } \\
 \hline
\begin{itemize}
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\item asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\item asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj
\end{itemize}
\\

\hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss} } \\
 \hline
\begin{itemize}
\item asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\item asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\item asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj
\end{itemize}
\\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss} } \\
 \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
$ \xymatrixcolsep{-1.5pc}
 \medmath{\xymatrix{
  & \mathbf{m[x][x]} \ar[dl] \ar[dr] & \\
    \mathbf{m[x][x]/\mathit{m(x,x)}} \ar[dr] & & \mathbf{m[x][x]/\mathit{m(m,x)}} \ar[dl] \\
   & \mathbf{m[x]/\varphi(x)\cong x(x\textsuperscript{x})} & &
}} $
 &
\hspace*{-1.5pc}
$ \xymatrixcolsep{1pc}%
\medmath{\xymatrix{
  & & \mathbf{\mathbb{K}[x]} \ar[dl] \ar[dr] & \\
   & \mathbf{\mathbb{K}[x]/\mathit{m(x)} \mathrlap{=\mathbb{K}[a]}} \ar[dr] &\hspace*{5pc} &\mathbf{\mathbb{K}[x]} \ar[dl]\quad \\
  & & \mathbf{\mathbb{K}/k\mathbb{K}} & &
}} $
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss} } \\
 \hline
\begin{itemize}
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\end{itemize}
\\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss}} \\
 \hline
\begin{itemize}
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\end{itemize}
\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{\strut FFF and NNN }
}
\end{table}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.6mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{table}
{\rowcolors{2}{gray!0!black!0}{gray!0!white!0}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ |X|X|}
\hline
\centering \textbf{\uline{Function Field Sieve}} \vspace{2mm}& {\centering \textbf{\uline{Number Field Sieve}}} \\
\hline \hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss} } \\
 \hline
\begin{itemize}
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\item asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\item asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj
\end{itemize}
\\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss} } \\
 \hline
\begin{itemize}
\item asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\item asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj
\end{itemize}
&

\begin{itemize}
\item asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\item asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj asmlj
asmlj asmlj
\end{itemize}
\\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss} } \\
 \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
$ \xymatrixcolsep{-1.5pc}
\medmath{\xymatrix{
 & & \mathbf{m[x][x]} \ar[dl] \ar[dr] & \\
 & \mathbf{m[x][x]/\mathit{m(x,x)}} \ar[dr] & & \mathbf{m[x][x]/\mathit{m(m,x)}} \ar[dl] \\
 & & \mathbf{m[x]/\varphi(x)\cong x(x\textsuperscript{x})} & &
}} $
 & \hspace*{-1.5pc}
$ \xymatrixcolsep{1pc}
 \medmath{\xymatrix{
 & & \mathbf{\mathbb{K}[x]} \ar[dl] \ar[dr] & \\
 & \mathbf{\mathbb{K}[x]/\mathit{m(x)}\mathrlap{ = \mathbb{K}[a]}} \ar[dr] & \hspace*{5pc} & \mathbf{\mathbb{K}[x]} \ar[dl] \quad\\
 & & \mathbf{\mathbb{K}/k\mathbb{K}} & &
}} $

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss} } \\
 \hline
\begin{itemize}
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\end{itemize}
\\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!90!black!50}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Aaaaaaaaa Kssssssss}} \\
 \hline
\begin{itemize}
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item aaaa asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas asas
asas asas asas asas asas
\end{itemize}
\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{\strut FFF and NNN }
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to remove  these rectangles that are coming in pdf?

Comment: @TanmaySharma - Just delete (or comment out) the instructions `\usepackage{showframe}` and `\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}`.

Comment: @Mico Could you please help me in getting left side line that is missing in the table.

Comment: @TanmaySharma - Just curious: Is there a reason for why you're not asking the creator of the answer (@Bernard) to address the missing-left-sideline issue?

Comment: @Tanmay Sharma: In the `tabularx` preambles, replace `{|@{}X|X|@{}}` with `{|X|X|}`. Sorry for the error in the code. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you so much. It works! I don't have enough privileges, otherwise I'll upvote your answer. Right now I can only accept your answer. Thank you once again.